# Vuetifyjs form validation with mask

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I create one v-form in my component, inside this v-form I put a v-text-field with a mask and a rule to not null

```
<v-text-field mask="###.###" :rule="[v => !!v || 'Required']"> ... </v-text-field>
```

but if my user type 22, when I try to validate the form I fot valid (because the text are not null, in my rules) but he don't match with my mask.. how can I get both validations? tks

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to check value.

`:rule="[v => !!v || 'Required', v => /^\d{3}\.\d{3}$/.test(v) || 'Invalid format']"`

**Edit**

Interesting, . (dot) is not part of value, so better answer would be:

`:rule="[v => !!v || 'Required', v => /\d{6}/.test(v) || 'Invalid format']"`

Live example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWBPqv?editors=1010)